# How to handle clicks / touches on repeated custom components?

Tags: android, android-layout

So, I have a screen that has from 0 to 6 of the same user interface components included via XML.  Something similar to this:

```
<TableRow android:layout_height="150px">

    <include android:id="@+id/p1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/numerics_component"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_height="150px">

    <include android:id="@+id/p2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/numerics_component"
        android:layout_below="@id/p1" android:onClick="onClick" />


</TableRow>
```

... etc

Each of those included UI's is a collection of several widgets and custom components that I am reusing.

I want to detect clicks on components in those included bits in my Activity and respond appropriately.  The problem is, in my onClick method if I follow the common pattern, I can never tell which of the views got a click:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    Log.d(loggingName, "Got onClick event on view: " + view);

    // Identify the view, and handle appropriately:
    switch (view.getId()) {

    ...
```

With the above code I can never tell which of the 6 copies of the component got clicked.  There must be a good way to do this, but I am not seeing it.

Further, I don't want to hard code the reusable component to one activity because I want to reuse it throughout multiple activities in my app.  So ideally, I'd be able to setup the listeners in my Activity.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) The Android View class allows you to tag each instance of a view via the [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

So, just `setTag()` on each view with some unique Integer, or even perhaps an object with a method that you will invoke.  Then in your click listener, just do a `getTag()` to differentiate between the various view instances.

2) You can put a unique onClickListener on each of the view instances.

3) You could do a `findViewById()` on each of the view instances, and store them in member variables, an array, or some other data structure.  Then in your `onClickListener`, you simply compare the View reference passed to `onClick()` against your list of saved references.

Comment: So, basically when my Activity loads it needs to loop through the 6 possible included areas and setTag() each component in the subarea with an ID?  That seems like it will work but its ugly as hell.  I'll give it a shot and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: You could also set a unique click handler on each View instance.  But that's not any less ugly.    For some reason unbeknownst to me, View.getId() doesn't work reliably.

Comment: Added one more option - compare saved object references against the value passed to onClick().  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could search the hierarchy to figure out which sub-component has been clicked. I see that each row of your table has a unique id. Thus, even though the layout is being repeated with identical ids, the view hierarchy does not have identical ids in any sub-tree.

Thus, to identify which sub-component has been clicked obtain the id of the parent view (which in your case is a row) and see which one of the 6 rows the view belongs to. Does that make sense?